# How to load local pdf to edit it with pdflib?

Tags: javascript, pdf, filesystems

I need to edit a pdf local/client-sided, but I don't know how to load the pdf without fetch/node. Usually the code would be like this:

```
const formUrl = 'https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/dod_character.pdf'
const formPdfBytes = await fetch(formUrl).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: @KJ The pdf is/would already be in the user's local storage.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn how to access local files inside the browser, have a look at [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications) on MDN.

For example, if you have file input like this in your HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="input" accept=".pdf">
```

When the user chooses a file, you can handle the event, get the [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object, and load its contents using [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) like this:

```
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const pdfDocument = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(await file.arrayBuffer());
    // do something with pdfDocument
});
```